# Characterization of prime ideals of $S^{-1}R$ when $S=1+I$, $I$ an ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

How can we characterize the prime ideals of $S^{-1}R$ when  $S=1+I$, and  $I$ is an ideal?

Clearly if $p$ is a prime containing $I$ then $S^{-1}p$ is a prime  of $S^{-1}R$

Comment: The prime ideals of $S^{-1} R$ are in correspondence with the prime ideals of $R$ whose intersection with $S$ is empty.  Also, $J\cap(1+I) = \emptyset \iff I+J \neq R$.

Answer (score 1):

They are characterized the same as in any ring of fractions:

> There is a one-to-one correspondence between prime ideals $P$ of $R$ that are disjoint from $S$ and prime ideals $Q$ of $S^{-1}R$ given by $P \mapsto S^{-1}P$ and $Q \mapsto h^{-1}(Q)$.

The reason it works in your case: $I \subseteq P$ a prime ideal in $R$ is because $P \cap S = \emptyset$.

If, by way of contradiction $P \cap S \neq \emptyset$, then there exists $p \in P$ and $p \in S = 1 + I$ which means $p = 1 + i$ for some $i \in I \subseteq P$. But this implies that $1 \in P$, contradicting that $P$ is prime (as prime ideals are proper).

Comment: Details on why that characterization is true can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054374/prime-ideals-in-a-and-prime-ideals-in-s-1a/1160519#1160519)